# Turning an ActiveRecord::Relation into a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

very beginner question.
I am using Rails 3's query interface as shown:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.authenticate
 if Rails.env = 'development'
   self.where('username = ?', 'development_user')
 else
   self.where('username = ?', request.env['REMOTE_USER'])
 end
end

end
```

This is returning an ActiveRecord::Relation object, where in reality I want the User object that relates to the query. How do I turn this into a User object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to "commit" the query with `all`, `first`, or `find`.

```
def self.authenticate
 user = Rails.env.development? ? "development_user" : request.env['REMOTE_USER']
 self.where('username = ?', user).first
end
```

Comment: Note it appears that using 'all' with 'where(..)' is deprecated in Rails4.  When I tried it on a recent version of Rails I got this warning:

    DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to     
    eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. 
    `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array 
    of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. 
    `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from irb_binding at  
    (irb):39)